# latest changes not update immediatly in PWA studion theme

Tags: pwa, pwa-studio, magento2.3.1

while working with PWA studio **venia** theme, if we update anything in admin like add a new category or add new product those are not effecting in **PWA studio theme** instance is there any way that our changes direct reflect on **PWA venia theme**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also faced this same issue, although I still need to figure out what is the exact root cause and good solution, but I can suggest you a instant solution that I tried and worked for me.

1. open `pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/.env`
2. `MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_ADD_UNIQUE_HASH=1`
3. Uncomment `MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SUBDOMAIN` (remove #) and give a value
     `MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SUBDOMAIN='narendra`'
4. Run commands:

   `yarn run watch:venia`

Now you will get a new development instance navigate to the same in an incognito window and check.

What I figured out is that may be there is some sort of caching due to which changes are not reflecting on same url.

Comment: MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SUBDOMAIN='narendra' any host file entry is required after changing this? I am getting URL "like 0.0.0.0:8098". Please help.

Comment: Try building from root user with sudo and also use secure url I.e. https

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was doing the same, built with Sudo and https is enabled. Got this message "could not configure or access custom host. using loopback"

Comment: You will be in need to provide some more information, better to provide with some screen-shots or the steps that you followed.

Comment: sure will update those details